# Unemployment with Insiders-Outsiders. What is a core employee?

Tags: unemployment, new-keynesian-economics

In Dynamic Macroeconomics book, by Alogoskoufis, on chapter 17, he analyses a model of aggregate ﬂuctuations that is based on periodic nominal wage contracts and can explain involuntary unemployment (a Gray-Fischer-Taylor type of model).

The main distortion is represented as the inability of unemployed/outsiders to influence the determination of nominal wages.

He then describes the objective of insiders as setting the maximum nominal wage, which will minimize expected deviations of employment from the target level of the number of insiders.

The employment target of insiders in period t is determined by $\bar n( j)t= δl( j)_{t−1}+ (1 − δ) \bar n( j)$, where the $j$ index represents firm $j$, and $l_{t-1}(j)$ number of employed in the previous period.

$\bar n( j)$ is the logarithm of the number of *core* employees of ﬁrm j, assumed exogenous.

What are the *core* employees? Could it be represented by a union in reality?